# Procedure has no parameters and arguments were supplied. although I have supplied

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have created a stored procedure and pass the parameter `@ID`:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetEmployeeID
AS
    DECLARE @ID NUMERIC (10) 
    SET @ID = @ID
BEGIN
    SELECT * 
    FROM [Employees] 
    WHERE EmployeeID = @ID
END
```

Executing it like this:

```
EXEC  GetEmployeeID 8;
```

But I get this error:

> Msg 8146, Level 16, State 2, Procedure GetEmployeeID, Line 0 Procedure
>   GetEmployeeID has no parameters and arguments were supplied.

Answer (score 0):

Your stored procedure does not have any input parameters. `ID` is local variable and it is not visible outside. You should use:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetEmployeeID 
     @ID NUMERIC(10)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT * 
    FROM [Employees] 
    WHERE EmployeeID = @ID;
END;

EXEC GetEmployeeID @ID = 8;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=9ba4542598c2e74a6c60956b1aae52ae)**